# Thread synchronization - when to terminate the thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I am writing a program which takes some input; a directory, a file name and some flags. The program's purpose is to search through the given directory for the given file. And while searching, if it finds another directory it will open up that directory and continue the search there. One of the flags allow the user to choose how many threads the program will use to search for the file.

The directories are stored in a stack and the problem I have is the synchronization between the threads. I am currently using a mutex together with a timed wait condition. Which means the thread will end if it has waited a certain amount of time AND the stack which stores the directories is empty. The problem is that, when only running 2 threads, 1 thread could end up doing all the work, that is opening 400 directories while the other opened 0.

So my question is... how can I synchronize my threads in a better way? Maybe without using the timed wait condition? When should the thread terminate?

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void search_func(char *path, char *name, int d, int f, int l);
void *thread_func(void *arg);
void push(char *data);
char* pop();
#define MAXLENGTH 1000
#define MAXSIZE 10000
#define WAIT_TIME_SECONDS 0.1
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;
struct stack
{
    char stk[MAXSIZE][MAXLENGTH];
    int top;
};
typedef struct stack STACK;
STACK s;

struct arg_keeper {
    char **argv;
    int argc;
    int d;
    int f;
    int l;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *xValue = NULL;
    int x;
    int d = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int nrthr = 0;
    opterr = 0;
    int thread_count = 0;
    int directory_exist = 0;
    pthread_t tid[1024];

    while ((x = getopt(argc, argv, "t:p:")) != -1) {
        switch (x) {
        case 't':
            xValue = optarg;
            if (*xValue == 'd') {
                d = 1;
            } else if (*xValue == 'f') {
                f = 1;
            } else if (*xValue == 'l') {
                l = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 'p':
            nrthr = atoi(optarg);
            if(nrthr == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid thread count\n");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        case '?':
            if (isprint (optopt))
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option '-%c'.\n",
                                optopt);
            return 1;
        default:
            abort();
        }
    }

    if (argc >= 3) {
        int i;
        for (i = optind; i < argc - 1; i++) {
            directory_exist = 1;
            push(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    if(directory_exist == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No directories entered\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct arg_keeper * arg_struct = malloc(sizeof(*arg_struct));
    arg_struct->argv = argv;
    arg_struct->argc = argc;
    arg_struct->d = d;
    arg_struct->f = f;
    arg_struct->l = l;

    if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Mutex initialisation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(pthread_cond_init(&count_threshold_cv, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Condition variable initialisation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(thread_count < nrthr - 1) {
        if(pthread_create(&(tid[thread_count++]), NULL, thread_func,
                            arg_struct) != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't create thread\n");
    }

    if(nrthr!=0)
        thread_func(arg_struct);
    else
        thread_func(arg_struct);

    int c;
    for(c = 0; c < nrthr; c++) {
        pthread_join(tid[c], NULL);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    free(arg_struct);
    return 0;
}

void *thread_func(void *arg) {
    int dirOpened = 0;
    struct arg_keeper arg_struct = *(struct arg_keeper *)arg;
    char *data;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    struct timespec ts;
    struct timeval tp;
    while(1) {
        gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
        ts.tv_sec  = tp.tv_sec;
        ts.tv_nsec = tp.tv_usec * 1000;
        ts.tv_sec += WAIT_TIME_SECONDS;

        if (pthread_cond_timedwait(&count_threshold_cv, &lock, &ts) == ETIMEDOUT) {
            if (s.top) {
                data = pop();
                pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
                dirOpened++;
                search_func(data, arg_struct.argv[arg_struct.argc - 1], arg_struct.d,
                        arg_struct.f, arg_struct.l);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    fprintf(stdout, "Thread with id %lu opened %d directories\n",
                pthread_self(), dirOpened);
    return NULL;
}

void search_func(char *inPath, char *testName, int d, int f, int l) {
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    strcpy(path, inPath);
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    DIR *pDir;
    struct stat file_info;

    if ((pDir = opendir(path)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:'%s': %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        int v1;
        int v2;
        char *str1 = ".";
        char *str2 = "..";

        char name[PATH_MAX];
        strcpy(name, testName);

        char testPath[PATH_MAX];
        strcpy(testPath, path);

        char testPathLast[PATH_MAX];
        strcpy(testPathLast, path);

        while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, name) == 0 && d == 0 &&
                    f == 0 && l == 0) {
                if (path[strlen(path) - 1] != '/')
                    strcat(testPathLast, "/");

                strcat(testPathLast, pDirent->d_name);
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", testPathLast);
            }

            char testPath2[PATH_MAX];
            strcpy(testPath2, testPath);
            strcat(testPath2, "/");
            strcat(testPath2, pDirent->d_name);

            if (lstat(testPath2, &file_info) != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "lstat error2: %s\n",
                            strerror(errno));

            if (d == 1) {
                if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, name)
                    == 0 && S_ISDIR(file_info.st_mode)) {
                    if (path[strlen(path) - 1] != '/')
                        strcat(testPathLast, "/");

                    strcat(testPathLast, pDirent->d_name);
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", testPathLast);
                }
            }

            if (f == 1) {
                if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, name)
                    == 0 && S_ISREG(file_info.st_mode)) {
                    if (path[strlen(path) - 1] != '/')
                        strcat(testPathLast, "/");

                    strcat(testPathLast, pDirent->d_name);
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", testPathLast);
                }
            }

            if (l == 1) {
                if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, name)
                    == 0 && S_ISLNK(file_info.st_mode)) {
                    if (path[strlen(path) - 1] != '/')
                        strcat(testPathLast, "/");

                    strcat(testPathLast, pDirent->d_name);
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", testPathLast);
                }
            }

            v1 = strcmp(pDirent->d_name, str1);
            v2 = strcmp(pDirent->d_name, str2);

            if ((v1 != 0 && v2 != 0) && S_ISDIR(file_info.st_mode)) {
                strcpy(path, testPath);
                strcpy(path, testPath);
                if (path[strlen(path) - 1] != '/')
                    strcat(path, "/");
                strcat(path, pDirent->d_name);
                push(path);
            }
        }
        closedir(pDir);
    }
}

void push(char *data)
{
    if(s.top == (MAXSIZE - 1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack is full\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        s.top = s.top + 1;
        strcpy(&(s.stk[s.top][0]), data);
    }
    return;
}

char* pop()
{
    char *data;
    if(s.top == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack is empty\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        data = s.stk[s.top];
        s.top = s.top - 1;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: A mutex protects a shared resource against concurrent access. What is the shared resource here. And is it protected safely by the mutex? That is: Is the shared resource not accessed concurrently in any case (excluding concurrent read-only access)?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind would be to use semaphores and a list of directories to be searched. A thread waits on the semaphore for a directory to be searched. When there is one, it searches it, and adds the directory it finds inside it to the list, and post the semaphore that number of times. It's simply a producer/consumer situation, where producer and consumer thread are the sames. (see [link on WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem))

Answer (score 0):

While the OP's implementation is better solved using POSIX [`nftw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) or BSD [`fts`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) (both available in glibc in Linux), the underlying problem in this implementation is actually quite interesting: each worker thread initially consumes one datum, then processes for some time, and possibly produces additional datums.

The problem case is when all existing datums are consumed, but there are one or more worker threads, that may produce additional datums to be processed. Thus, having no more datums to be processed is not sufficient a reason for a worker thread to exit. A worker thread should only exit when there are no more datums to be processed, *and no worker thread that could generate additional datums running*.

The obvious solution is to use a mutex, a condition variable (for waiting for new datums), and a counter for the number of worker threads currently running.

Let's say the datums are stored in a singly-linked list:

```
struct work_item {
    struct work_item *next;
    char              path[];
};
```

The `path` member above is a C99 flexible array member. The structure we can use for describing the work to be done could be

```
struct work {
    pthread_mutex_t   mutex;
    pthread_cond_t    cond;
    long              active;
    struct work_item *item;
};
#define WORK_INITIALIZER {     \
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, \
    PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,  \
    0L, NULL }
```

After pushing the initial items to the `item` list, one or more threads are created, given the pointer to the shared `struct work` structure.

The logic is similar to the following:

```
void *worker_thread(void *work_ptr)
{
    struct work *const work = (struct work *)word_ptr;
    struct work_item  *item;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(work->mutex));

    while (1) {

        /* If there are no active workers,
           nor any work items, we're done. */
        if (!work->item && !work->active) {
            /* Ensure threads waiting on the condition
               variable are woken up, so they quit too. */
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&(work->cond));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(work->mutex));
            return NULL;
        }

        /* No work items left? */
        if (!work->item) {
            /* Wait for a new one to be produced,
               or a worker to notice we're done. */
            pthread_cond_wait(&(work->cond), &(work->mutex));
            continue;
        }

        /* Increment active worker count, grab an item,
           and work on it. */
        work->active++;
        item = work->item;
        work->item = work->item->next;
        item->next = NULL;

        /* Unlock mutex while working. */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(work->mutex));

        /*
         * TODO: Work on item
        */

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(work->mutex));
        work->active--;
    }
}
```

Of course, when working on an item, one must retake the mutex when pushing an item to the stack, and signal on the condition variable to wake up a worker thread (if one is waiting for new work):

```
        struct work_item *temp;

        /* TODO: Allocate and initialize temp */

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(work->mutex));
        temp->next = work->item;
        work->item = temp;
        pthread_cond_signal(&(work->cond));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(work->mutex));
```

Note how the active counter reflects the number of threads currently working on an item (and is, basically, the number of *producers* currently running). It is *not* the number of existing worker threads!

The condition variable is broadcast if a thread notices there are no more items to work on, nor any producers running, so that if there are any threads waiting for new work, will be woken up (and similarly notice there is no more work). The condition variable is also signaled (waking up only one waiting thread) whenever an item is added to the work list.

Comment: How exactly would you apply this to my code? I've tried using a variable to keep track of the working threads but it never works.

Comment: @Fjodor: Would it help if I implemented something other than directory scanning; say, some kind of string permutation (workers consuming one character, and producing either zero, one, or two new strings based on the one character they consumed)? I'd like you (and others reading this answer) to understand how to solve this kind of producer-consumer problem, but without showing a ready-made answer one could copy and paste and use as-is. That is, I'd love to help you understand one possible solution, but with you still having to apply it to your particular problem yourself.

Comment: I don't think so, I mean, I've been trying to get this to work for a while but I'm not able to work it around. Of course I will read and compare your answer to my other tried versions to see where I've gone wrong in the thought process. I think I know how to solve it, keeping track of the working directories as the 2nd argument as to when a thread should terminate (the first argument being the stack is empty). But I'm just not able to get it working.

Comment: @Fjodor: Unfortunately, I think your approach is fundamentally flawed. You cannot make a robust POSIX directory tree walkers without [`openat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/openat.2.html); using paths will only work on a static or read-only filesystem, as any directory moves or renames will completely throw a pure path/name-based walkers off. Furthermore, this is already a well solved problem (`nftw()`, `fts()`), and thus not very interesting. So no, I will not write such an implementation, even though the producer-consumer sub-problem *is* interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I synchronize my threads in a better way? Maybe without using the timed wait condition?

Yes - I'd drop the condition variable and use a set of two [semaphores](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semget.html), the first semaphore counting the pending directories on the stack, and the second semaphore counting the busy work threads. To keep the work threads simple, I'd do all search work in the created threads and not call `thread_func()` from `main()`. The `pthread_mutex_t lock` can be kept to protect the `STACK s` from concurrent accesses.

> When should the thread terminate?

As Nominal Animal wrote: *A worker thread should only exit when there are no more datums to be processed, and no worker thread that could generate additional datums running.* The above mentioned semaphores provide the required information and allow to easily wait for that condition in the `main()` thread.

The changes to your program would be

- in file scope:

  ```
  #include <sys/sem.h>
  int semid;
  ```
- in `push()`:

  ```
  void push(char *data)
  {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      if (s.top == MAXSIZE-1)
          fprintf(stderr, "Stack is full\n");
      else
          strcpy(s.stk[++s.top], data),
          semop(semid, &(struct sembuf){0, 1}, 1);    // add 1 to "dirs on stack"
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
      return;
  }
  ```

  Note that we count up the first semaphore here.
- in `pop()`:

  ```
  char *pop()
  {
      char *data;
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      if (s.top == -1)
          fprintf(stderr, "Stack is empty\n"),
          data = NULL;
      else
          data = strdup(s.stk[s.top--]);  // Don't return freed stack slot!
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
      return data;
  }
  ```

  Note that we return a copy of the data rather than just a pointer to it, since the freed top of stack can be reused and overwritten by another thread at any time.
- in `main()` before the directory arguments are pushed on the stack:

  ```
      // create semaphore set of 2 sems: [0] dirs on stack, [1] threads at work
      semid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2, S_IRWXU);
      semctl(semid, 0, SETALL, (unsigned short [2]){});   // zero the sem values
  ```

  Note that this has to be placed before the first call to `push()`, so that it can count up the semaphore.
- in `main()` where threads are created and `thread_func()` was called:

  ```
      while (thread_count < nrthr)
          if (pthread_create(&tid[thread_count++], NULL, thread_func, arg_struct))
              fprintf(stderr, "Can't create thread\n");

      // wait until no more dirs on stack and no more threads at work
      semop(semid, (struct sembuf []){{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, 2);
      semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID); // remove the semaphores, make threads finish
  ```

  Note that we create `nrthr` rather than `nrthr - 1` threads, since the `main()` thread doesn't participate in the work, it just waits for all work being done. Then, it destroys the set of semaphores and so causes the work threads to get out of their loop and finish (see below).
- in `thread_func()`:

  ```
  void *thread_func(void *arg)
  {
      int dirOpened = 0;
      struct arg_keeper arg_struct = *(struct arg_keeper *)arg;
      char *data;
      // wait for work, subtract 1 from dirs on stack and add 1 to threads at work
      while (semop(semid, (struct sembuf []){{0, -1}, {1, 1}}, 2) == 0)
      {   // this loop ends when semid is removed
          data = pop();
          dirOpened++;
          search_func(data, arg_struct.argv[arg_struct.argc-1],
                      arg_struct.d, arg_struct.f, arg_struct.l);
          free(data);
          semop(semid, &(struct sembuf){1, -1}, 1);   // "threads at work" -= 1
      }
      fprintf(stdout, "Thread with id %lu opened %d directories\n",
              pthread_self(), dirOpened);
      return (void *)dirOpened;
  }
  ```

  Note that `semop()` returns *-1* when `main()` has destroyed the semaphore set, and so the loop ends. Also note that we free the data copy that has been allocated in `pop()`.